# Toggling a high-power relay with a Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, current, relay

I've got some relays connected to some 230V high-current spotlights.
I would like to control 16 of these with a microcontroller.
I'm thinking of creating my own PCB.

> I have checked the datasheet, it's the 22.32.0.024.4520
>   (http://datasheet.octopart.com/22.32.0.024.4520-Finder-datasheet-10127161.pdf)
>   but I can't really find the required voltage or amperage to switch on
>   this relay.
>
> > Peter Bennet: 91 mA (24 volt at 2.2 Watts)

I'm thinking of connecting it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzKjJU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using another relay isn't really an option, since I've got them in stock and they work for the spotlights I have.

> I'm not a 100% sure if the diode is necessary. The component names
>   also aren't final.
>
> > Richard Crowley: Protection of reverse voltage generated by the collapsing magnetic field. You might want a 1N4002 or higher for that.

Would this application provide enough "protection" for the microcontroller? I don't see how the 24V is a problem to the microcontroller (and other devices connected) but it might just be?

Comment: Please go read this question, and update your schematic. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics

Comment: As I decode the part number (look at "Ordering Information" on page 3 of the datasheet), the relay has a 24 volt AC/DC coil rated at 2.2 Watts - that would be about 91 mA.

Comment: @peterbennet Ah, thanks! I was looking for an amperage in the datasheet, didn't think I would have to calculate it (: but in that case I wouldn't need a very heavy FET, might even check if there are optocouplers that can do a 24V 100mA for "safety".

Comment: @MattYoung I've checked my design against the "design guidelines" and updated it. If you feel something is still wrong, please let me know, I couldn't find more mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRF530 transistor is rated at 10A.  It is more than adequate for controlling a load of ~0.1A (2.2W / 24V).*

The diode D1 is required to protect the transistor from the reverse voltage generated by the collapsing magnetic field of the relay coil when you turn it off. I would recommend using something more substantial like 1N4002 or higher. That diode will handle quite a lot of power (for a few milliseconds) and I would be afraid that 1N4148 is rather wimpy for that application.

Remember to use a logic-rated ("sensitive gate") FET or you won't be able to control a 24V load from a 5V microcontroller output.

- I have a handy Ohm's Law calculator online here: http://www.rcrowley.com/eirp.htm

I used it to calculate the current from your statement that the coil voltage rating is 24V, and the spec sheet you referenced says that the coil wants 2.2W

Comment: Would there be any use to isolate the 24V from the 5V? Since I might put an ethernet/RS485 connection on it. I don't see how it could go wrong, but if 24V goes through the RS485 connection, I could fry all bus devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you used a Solid State Relay , you would not have to contend with noise, arcing contacts, and you would not need a protection diode.   Silent Operation as well.

Comment: This application is suitable for them, Tim. ;^)

Comment: The spots aren't very well documented. And they seemed to have a large inrush/inductive current which broke other relays. Solid State Relays seem interesting but the spot+relay set-up is working at the moment, so I'd rather not change that.